Anyone have a download link for Tuxera 2015?
I’m following a tutorial on how to install Windows 10 on older Macs. I’m trying to install windows 10 on my Late 2008 MacBook 13” Aluminum Unibody with 4GB RAM and 512GB SSD. I can’t find a link to download the 2015 version of Tuxera, because I keep either getting redirected to random crap, or I get download links of the 2020/2021 version instead of the 2015 one. Stupid people trying to hide certain apps from me.

Just out of curiosity, can you give a link to the tutorial?

Have you tried contacting the developer's of Tuxera directly?
